# jQuery token-input not processing cross-domain results

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, jquery-tokeninput

I'm creating a chrome extension which uses http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ to add tokens, see [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541612/chrome-extension-error-when-returning-json-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-t).

I am confused as to how to get results from my server to be processed by tokenInput. The following article, [What is JSONP?](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/), suggests that I need to add a callback query param to get cross-domain jsonp working:

```
$(function() {
  $("#token").tokenInput("http://localhost/token/search?callback=jsonprocess", {
    preventDuplicates: true,
    crossDomain: true,
  });
});
```

This is used to wrap the response in my php code:

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo $this->request->query('callback') . '(' . json_encode($token_array) . ')';
exit;
```

Which then calls the `jsonprocess()` method in my javascript. However this is out of context of the tokenInput instance so I can't populate the results. Is this the correct functionality? Or is there a way to make the jQuery tokeninput plugin process the jsonp directly?

The success callback in tokeninput:

```
ajax_params.success = function(results) {
    cache.add(cache_key, $(input).data("settings").jsonContainer ? results[$(input).data("settings").jsonContainer] : results);
    if($.isFunction($(input).data("settings").onResult)) {
        results = $(input).data("settings").onResult.call(hidden_input, results);
    }
};
```

...is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than I thought; don't need `?callback=jsonprocess` in the search url

```
$(function() {
  $("#token").tokenInput("http://localhost/token/search", {
    preventDuplicates: true,
    crossDomain: true,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [jQuery Tokeninput documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), `crossDomain` must be set as `true` in options, if you want to it to be a jsonp request.

```
$(function() {
  $("#token").tokenInput("http://localhost/token/search?callback=jsonprocess", {
    preventDuplicates: true,
    crossDomain: true
  });
});
```

and [The *right* JSON content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) is `application/json`.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

### UPDATE:

Ok if it's not working with jsonp you should try it by [enabling CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).

Here what you will do,

```
$(function() {
  $("#token").tokenInput("http://localhost/token/search?callback=jsonprocess", {
    preventDuplicates: true,
    crossDomain: false, //it's also false as default.
  });
});
```

in PHP you must enable CORS, and you don't need to take result into the callback function. you will dump only JSON.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode($token_array);
exit;
```

Comment: Good spot, I missed the crossDomain flag when copying my code across. I've amended my question. I've changed the header to `application/json` but it is still not working. It is still just triggering the callback method and not processing the results in the success callback.

Comment: @xylar Ok, look my updated answer. And Have you checked http://localhost/token/search, Is that a right JSON result? And have you checked console for extension, what javascript error are you getting?

Comment: yes that's right, than you should accept your own answer. It will help people who has same problem with you.

Answer (score 0):

Dude you need callback in javascript and php like this:

**javascript:**

```
script.php?callback=?&your_parametars_here
```

**and in php**

```
echo $_GET['callback'].$your_data_here
```

Comment: Thanks, I think my problem was that I had set a value for callback=jsonprocess and I didn't need to add it, see my answer.